# Convert url query key-value pairs to data frame

Tags: r, url, dataframe, key-value

How can I parse url query strings, which essentially are key-value pairs into a typical data.frame? Is there a straightforward way to do this in R? Maybe with a library?

Input:

```
unique1=blub&same=aaaa-aaaa-aaaa&date=01.01.2017&time=12:30:00
date=02.01.2017&unique2=blub&time=12:30:00&same=bbbb-bbbb
same=cccc&time=12:35:00&unique3=blub&date=03.01.2017`
```

Desired Output as data.frame:

```
        date           same     time unique1 unique2 unique3
1 01.01.2017 aaaa-aaaa-aaaa 12:30:00    blub    <NA>    <NA>
2 02.01.2017      bbbb-bbbb 12:30:00    <NA>    blub    <NA>
3 03.01.2017           cccc 12:35:00    <NA>    <NA>    blub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method. Note that fields are split by "&" and the "key-value" are split by "=". Then, we use `strsplit` to produce a list of each line, using both characters to split. In the second line, exploit the regularity of the data, using modulus 2 to separate keys from values. This returns a nested list so that we can feed it to `data.table`'s `rbindlist` to return a `data.table`

```
# get list of key-values by line
tmp <- strsplit(urlDat, "&|=")
# use modulus to select keys and values
tmp <- lapply(tmp, function(x) setNames(as.list(x[seq_along(x) %% 2 == 0L]),
                                         x[seq_along(x) %% 2 == 1L]))
library(data.table)
dat <- rbindlist(tmp, fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)
```

this returns

```
dat
   unique1           same       date     time unique2 unique3
1:    blub aaaa-aaaa-aaaa 01.01.2017 12:30:00      NA      NA
2:      NA      bbbb-bbbb 02.01.2017 12:30:00    blub      NA
3:      NA           cccc 03.01.2017 12:35:00      NA    blub
```

The columns are out of order, but this is easy enough to fix with the standard indexing, `[`.

```
setDF(dat)[, c("date", "same", "time", "unique1", "unique2", "unique3")]
        date           same     time unique1 unique2 unique3
1 01.01.2017 aaaa-aaaa-aaaa 12:30:00    blub    <NA>    <NA>
2 02.01.2017      bbbb-bbbb 12:30:00    <NA>    blub    <NA>
3 03.01.2017           cccc 12:35:00    <NA>    <NA>    blub
```

where `setDF` coerces dat into a data.frame in place (no copies).

**data**

```
urlDat <- readLines(textConnection(
"unique1=blub&same=aaaa-aaaa-aaaa&date=01.01.2017&time=12:30:00
date=02.01.2017&unique2=blub&time=12:30:00&same=bbbb-bbbb
same=cccc&time=12:35:00&unique3=blub&date=03.01.2017"))
```