# How to convert a string that has the headers and values with ID per string into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to know how to convert strings in the text file into a data frame for analysis.

I got one line which has an ID per customer, which has the column heading and value in and is separated by semi colon ';'
For example:

```
{ID=12345;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:42"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""WiLoMonitorStart"";Text=""mnew inactivity failure on cable"";}
```

The column headings are ID, TimeStamp, Event, Status, Text and any others that come before the equal "=" sign.
The values under the column headings will be after the equals sign "=", see the picture this is the end result I want to achieve.

```
Statements {    
    "{ID=12345;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:42"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""WiLoMonitorStart"";Text=""mnew inactivity failure on cable"";}"
    "{ID=12346;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:43"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""MetroCode"";Text=""AU"";}"
    "{ID=12347;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:43"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""LoWiValidation"";Text=""Password validation 2.5GHz for AES: BigBong"";}"
    "{ID=12349;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:42"";Event=DomainEvent;MacAddress=""AB:23:34:EF:YN:OT"";LogTime=""2019-02-26 00:15:48"";Domain=""Willing ind"";SecondaryDomain=""No_Perl"";}"
    "{ID=12351;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:45"";Event=CollectionCallEvent;SerialNumber=""34121"";}"
    "{ID=12352;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:46"";Event=CollectionCallEvent;SerialNumber=""34151"";Url=""werlkdfa/vierjwerret/vre34f3/df343rsdf343+t45rf/dfgr3443"";}"
}
```

}

[image]

You can see the semi colon ";" separates each variable, can someone be able to separate and make R identify what is a column heading and what is a value to be placed underneath the respected heading with respect to the customer ID (the primary key).

Note that each line may not have the same column headings for the next one.

The image supplied is what I want to achieve in the end but I am having great difficulty to do so in R. It is not a json file or a XML format it is a file that was dumped in text format where I need to extract and analyse the information in a dataframe format before I can do any insights.

Any suggestions? Would there be a better way than say using regular expressions? E.g. **stringr package?**

Comment: by the way  besides values from ID and Event headings all having double quotation marks on the values. The quotation marks are a nuisance and need to be removed.

Comment: Please do not attempt to amend your question by using comments (and don't even respond to clarifying remarks in comments). Learn to use the [edit] facilities in SO. You should also clarify in what form this test currently resides. Is it a text file?

Comment: apart from this do you have an answer?

Comment: @Justin, have you seen the solution I posted yesterday? Does it help you?

Comment: Chris Ruehlemann you are a EPIC legend thank you ! I am super glad you used Tidyverse because using Base R is so difficult let alone Regular Expressions. Would Python be easier if you had the choice? From your experience would you still consider using R for your statistical analysis or would you start making the change to python because of the available options?

Comment: I only know a little about R (and tidyverse) but have no clue about Python, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(txt) %>%
  # tidy strings:
  mutate(txt = trimws(gsub("Statements|\\s{2,}|[^\\w=; -]", "", txt, perl = TRUE))) %>%
  # separate into rows by splitting on ";":
  separate_rows(txt, sep = ";") %>%
  # separate into two columns by splitting on "=":
  separate(txt, into = c("header", "value"), sep = "=") %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(header) %>%
  # create grouped row ID:
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # cast wider:
  pivot_wider(rowid, 
              names_from = "header", 
              values_from = "value")
# A tibble: 6 × 12
  rowid ID    TimeStamp         Event              Status Text  MacAd…¹ LogTime Domain Secon…² Seria…³ Url  
  <int> <chr> <chr>             <chr>              <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1     1 12345 2019-02-26 001542 StatusEvent        WiLoM… mnew… AB2334… 2019-0… Willi… No_Perl 34121   werl…
2     2 12346 2019-02-26 001543 StatusEvent        Metro… AU    NA      NA      NA     NA      34151   NA   
3     3 12347 2019-02-26 001543 StatusEvent        LoWiV… Pass… NA      NA      NA     NA      NA      NA   
4     4 12349 2019-02-26 001542 DomainEvent        NA     NA    NA      NA      NA     NA      NA      NA   
5     5 12351 2019-02-26 001545 CollectionCallEve… NA     NA    NA      NA      NA     NA      NA      NA   
6     6 12352 2019-02-26 001546 CollectionCallEve… NA     NA    NA      NA      NA     NA      NA      NA   
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​MacAddress, ²​SecondaryDomain, ³​SerialNumber
```

Data:

```
txt <- 'Statements {    
    "{ID=12345;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:42"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""WiLoMonitorStart"";Text=""mnew inactivity failure on cable"";}"
    "{ID=12346;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:43"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""MetroCode"";Text=""AU"";}"
    "{ID=12347;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:43"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""LoWiValidation"";Text=""Password validation 2.5GHz for AES: BigBong"";}"
    "{ID=12349;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:42"";Event=DomainEvent;MacAddress=""AB:23:34:EF:YN:OT"";LogTime=""2019-02-26 00:15:48"";Domain=""Willing ind"";SecondaryDomain=""No_Perl"";}"
    "{ID=12351;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:45"";Event=CollectionCallEvent;SerialNumber=""34121"";}"
    "{ID=12352;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:46"";Event=CollectionCallEvent;SerialNumber=""34151"";Url=""werlkdfa/vierjwerret/vre34f3/df343rsdf343+t45rf/dfgr3443"";}"
}   '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txt <- 'Statements {    
    "{ID=12345;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:42"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""WiLoMonitorStart"";Text=""mnew inactivity failure on cable"";}"
    "{ID=12346;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:43"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""MetroCode"";Text=""AU"";}"
    "{ID=12347;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:43"";Event=StatusEvent;Status=""LoWiValidation"";Text=""Password validation 2.5GHz for AES: BigBong"";}"
    "{ID=12349;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:42"";Event=DomainEvent;MacAddress=""AB:23:34:EF:YN:OT"";LogTime=""2019-02-26 00:15:48"";Domain=""Willing ind"";SecondaryDomain=""No_Perl"";}"
    "{ID=12351;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:45"";Event=CollectionCallEvent;SerialNumber=""34121"";}"
    "{ID=12352;TimeStamp=""2019-02-26 00:15:46"";Event=CollectionCallEvent;SerialNumber=""34151"";Url=""werlkdfa/vierjwerret/vre34f3/df343rsdf343+t45rf/dfgr3443"";}"
}   ' # note need for single quotes
```

Then read in with readLines and remove leading and trailing lines and hten remove {,}, and the double quotes, and finally read with `scan`:

```
RL <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
rl <- RL[-1]
input <- scan(text=gsub('[{}"]',"", rl[1:6]), sep=';', what="")
input[1:12]
#------------------
[1] "    ID=12345"                                                 "TimeStamp=2019-02-26 00:15:42"                               
 [3] "Event=StatusEvent"                                            "Status=WiLoMonitorStart"                                     
 [5] "Text=mnew inactivity failure on cable"                        ""                                                            
 [7] "    ID=12346"                                                 "TimeStamp=2019-02-26 00:15:43"                               
 [9] "Event=StatusEvent"                                            "Status=MetroCode"                                            
[11] "Text=AU"                                                      ""
```

Then you can process like any key-value pair input with "ID" being the delimiter. Another way that woud keep the origianl lines together in a list would be:

```
sapply( gsub('[{}"]',"", rl[1:6]), function(x) scan(text=x, sep=";", what=""))
#----------------
Read 6 items
Read 6 items
Read 6 items
Read 8 items
Read 5 items
Read 6 items
$`    ID=12345;TimeStamp=2019-02-26 00:15:42;Event=StatusEvent;Status=WiLoMonitorStart;Text=mnew inactivity failure on cable;`
[1] "    ID=12345"                          "TimeStamp=2019-02-26 00:15:42"         "Event=StatusEvent"                    
[4] "Status=WiLoMonitorStart"               "Text=mnew inactivity failure on cable" ""    
# only printed the result from the first line
```

[Convert url query key-value pairs to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570043/convert-url-query-key-value-pairs-to-data-frame)

Comment: thank you for showing the ropes of Regular Expressions and converting this into a Dataframe. Scan() ...thats the function I need to use ...interesting ! I have tried learning a lot of regular expressions free online, there is a lot more I need to know again many thanks!

Comment: I used regex to strip the surrounding json-like punctuation, then passed the stripped text to `scan` which processed it as it would a raw text file.The `scan` function is what the `read.*` functions use. It does much less checking and processing than do the `read.*` functions.